# How to create rounded corner using photoshop cs2?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs2

In my application there is the requirement of the image with the rounded shape.
I am new to use Photoshop so I want to know how it is possible to create the rounded shape of any existing image ?

The image is below:

[image]

Please give me the steps to create it as I am new to Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can create rounded corners with the help of rounded rectangle tool

[image]

You can adjust roundness of corners by putting radius amount in radius box, you can also create any size of rounded corner box..

[image]

---

If you want to create one sided  rounded corners of any existing image follow this instruction mentioned in image.(Open in new window for clarity)

and if you want to create rounded corners of whole image just place the box in top of your image  and follow the same instructions...

[image]

Hope this will help....

Comment: Your welcome buddy :)

Answer (score -3):

CS2 does not have rounded corner selection tool...